# Checking database with ajax, use vibration API if successful

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, vibration

I'm working on a web-chat right now and only recently discovered the HTML5 vibration API, which is exactly what I could use.

Right now I'm calling an ajax-function every 5 seconds, which checks my MySQL-Database via a PHP-file.
When the echo is "1" it's supposed to write sth. in the console and vibrate for 1 second. When the echo is "0" nothing should happen.

It all works fine (Database gets checkes, console.log is submitted) except for the vibration - nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

The ajax code (only the relevant part):

```
function allebereit(){
    $.ajax({
       url: 'allebereit.php',
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data){
            if(data==1){
                navigator.vibrate(1000);
                console.log('works');
            }
            else {

            }
       }
    });
}
```

The allebereit.php code

```
<?php
include("config.php");

$sessionname = $_SESSION['sessionname'];

  $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM chatters WHERE route='$sessionname'";
        $result = mysqli_query($dblogin,$sql2); 
  $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM chatters WHERE route='$sessionname' && bereit='yes'";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($dblogin,$sql3); 

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)=='2' && mysqli_num_rows($result2)=='2') {
  echo 1;
 }
 elseif(mysqli_num_rows($result)=='3' && mysqli_num_rows($result2)=='3') {
  echo 1;
 }
  elseif(mysqli_num_rows($result)=='4' && mysqli_num_rows($result2)=='4') {
  echo 1;
 }
 else{
     echo 0;
 }

                ?>
```

Comment: `console.log(data)` and see what you're REALLY getting. if php outputs any warnings/errors, that'll become part of the output and make `== 1` fail. and note that num_rows() returns an INTEGER, not a string. there is NO point in doing `num_rows == '1'`.

Comment: maybe it's not supported by your browser? http://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-vibration-api/

Comment: @MarcB Just did that, return the correct data.

Comment: @wardk Tried some tutorials/examples online with the same phone/browser and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 if ($.trim(data) === 1) {
```

It may work ...